# apply code / macro for all subpackages BUILD.bazel files

Tags: bazel

Using bazel, I have a repetitive call to `load()` function at the beginning of all `BUILD.bazel` file.

Moreover, now I see that to test out my code (that extends bazel to another language) - I need to call some macro function in all of my build files.

Is there any way to apply custom code in all subpackages (without the need to write anything in the `BUILD.bazel` files)?

Comment: This seems to be something that buildozer should do - file a feature request here? https://github.com/bazelbuild/buildtools/tree/master/buildozer

Comment: Recommendation is to repeat the code. It's okay to have `load()` statements at the top of your files (just like in other languages).

Answer (score 1):

You can put in load statements into the `tools/build_rules/prelude_bazel` file in your workspace. For example the [Skydoc rules documentation](https://skydoc.bazel.build/docs/getting_started.html) rules mention adding the following to your `prelude_bazel` file.

```
load(
    "@io_bazel_skydoc//skylark:skylark.bzl",
    "skydoc_repositories",
    "skylark_library",
    "skylark_doc",
)
```